# How to differentiate between "0" and "00" in a string and replace substring

Tags: java, substring

In a string, how can I replace all "0" with X and all "00" with Y, but if it's more than 2 zeros just leave it as is.

For Example: `00 0 000 0000 0`

Example output: `Y X 000 0000 X`

Comment: well, what distinguishes a lone zero from a double zero? The fact that there are whitespaces before and after it. That also tells you how your replace statements can replace them, e.g. by instead of replacing `"0"` replace `" 0 "`, only the start and the end now need special handling.

Comment: You could look into regular expressions to do this.

Answer (score 4):

In Java 14+, you can do it like this:

```java
String input = "00 0 000 0000 0";

String result = Pattern.compile("0+").matcher(input).replaceAll(m ->
        switch (m.group().length()) {
            case 1 -> "X";
            case 2 -> "Y";
            default -> m.group();
        });

System.out.println(result); // prints: Y X 000 0000 X
```

Comment: oh, the length...I missed that approach

Answer (score 2):

You could solve this with regular expressions

```
String listOfNumbers = "00 0 000 0000 0";

listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.replaceAll("(^| )00( |$)", " Y ");
listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.replaceAll("(^| )0( |$)", " X ");
listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.trim();

System.out.println(listOfNumbers);
```

This code prints out `Y X 000 0000 X`

How it works: First the code checks to replace all occurrences of `00`, next it will take the intermediate result and wil check for `0`

- `(^| )`: We either expect the start of the String, or we expect a blank space character
- `00`: We expect 2 occurrences of the `0` character
- `( |$)`: Here we expect a blank space, or the end of the String
- `trim()` with this code, we will have a blank space at the beginning and end of our complete String. To solve this we need to trim those of.

**Alternatively**, you could use a more complex regex that prevents the use of a trim in the end:

```
String test = "00 0 000 0000 0";

test = test.replaceAll("(?<!0)(0{2})(?!0)", "Y");
test = test.replaceAll("(?<!0)(0{1})(?!0)", "X");

System.out.println(test);
```

This code also prints the same result `Y X 000 0000 X`

How this one works:

- `(?<!0)` Make sure that there are no extra 0 items before what we search. This is called a look behind
- `(0{2})` Check for 2 occurrences of 0. Alternatively you could also put `00` here instead of specifying we expect a `0` twice
- `(?!0)` Make sure that there are no extra 0 items behind what we search. This is called a look ahead

Comment: Far easier would be to simply replace if there is either start of expression or whitespace, then 1 or 2 zeros, then a whitespace or end of expression. Would not need this lookahead / lookbehind complexity.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct. I'll see to update the answer with a simpler regex like that

Comment: I've updated the code. It's indeed a lot easier. Thanks for the feedback. I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent the need for a trim though with this easier example. But compared to the harder style, it seems like an easy tradeoff to me

Comment: Hello Yoni, it seems you have too much spaces in there

Comment: I think you should remove space from "Y " and "X " and the code will work fine

Comment: Indeed, I've fixed it. Was just a copy paste error on my side

Answer (score 2):

*Two approaches without regex.*

---

Based on **Arvind**'s ternary operator improvement and **Andreas**' approach (***length***).

Also avoiding the trailing space, one liner loop.

```
String str = "00 0 000 0000 0";  
String[] pieces = str.split(" ");
str = "";
for (String s : pieces) {
   str += (str.length()>0 ? " ":"") + (s.length()==1 ? "X" : (s.length()==2 ? "Y" : s));
}       
//str => "Y X 000 0000 X"
```

---

Using ***equals***:

```
String base = "00 0 000 0000 0";  
String[] pieces = base.split(" ");
String rep="";

for (String s : pieces)
{
   if (s.equals("0"))
       rep+="X";
   else if (s.equals("00"))
       rep+="Y";
   else
       rep+=s;
    
   rep+=" ";
}

//rep = rep.trim(); -> if need to cut off the last space
System.out.println(rep); //  Y X 000 0000 X
```

Using the [ternary (or conditional) operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), you can shorten the code further:

```
for (String s : pieces) {
    rep += s.equals("0") ? "X" : (s.equals("00") ? "Y" : s);
    rep += " ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), I think one of the easiest one would be the following

Replace [`\b0\b` by `X`](https://regex101.com/r/yO9v5r/1) and also [`\b00\b` by `Y`](https://regex101.com/r/1UzDpd/1)